# ic relay.. is there any delay for the responz of <İC insıde the circuit

Tags: arduino, sensor, switches, relay

Regarding SPDT ic relay TS5A3157. Do we have a delay responz inside the İc/ do we have a click sound. Because im startıng for a new project that can switch wireless, bluetooth or ir. What i need on my project is an  actual or quick responz with no delay, if we have a delay may i know. How many milli seconds thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Go to www.TI.com 2) Using the search function at the top, search for TS5A3157 3) Click on "Download datasheet" 4) tON/tOFF listed on page 1 and also shown in Figure 17 (page 15)

Comment: thanks for the info sir Tut...i will try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

All the information you will need to use this device can be found in the datasheet, which can be downloaded from www.ti.com

This part is an analog switch, not a mechanical relay.  As it is entirely solid-state, it will not click when operated.

Note that the signal being switched must remain between Ground and Vcc.

Comment: thank you very much Peter for the quick responce here i really appriciate.the thing is i got visit the Tİ.com but im a bit confuse, im only a vocational Electronics and electrician..some of those i dont understand i dont know where to start . İ just heard this Arduino. so i decided to do a project for audio. Again thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As this is a solid state device, it does not have a mechanical switch and this will not make a click sound.

Regarding the delay: there is no switch in the world with zero delay. However this switch will turn on in about 6 ns and turn off in 3.5 ns. Therefore the delay is imperceptible to humans. The delay depends on several factors such as load capacitance see datasheet section 6.5 for details.